# invalidateLayout equivalent in iOS8

Tags: ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I find calling invalidateLayout in iOS8 to cause crashy behaviour, probably due to the new invalidateLayout with contexts introduced last WWDC. Still, I haven't found an equivalent to invalidating the whole collection view layout.

Say I want it all to happen exactly like iOS7's invalidateLayout. What should be done?

iOS7: [collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

iOS8: ???

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 8 you will want to invalidate the layout within a batch update block:

```
    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [layout invalidateLayout];
    } completion:nil];
```

Comment: What is the exact reason for this?